# Tabs en la terminal de Visual Studio

Tags: python, terminal

cuando imprimo datos con `tabs`, en la terminal me sale demasiado espacio solo para algunos datos, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?
ya he probado antes usar `ctrl + M` para hacer el focus pero no hace ningún cambio [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]como se mira en la imagen deja mucho espacio hasta al final lpone solo lo que cabe y lo demás lo pone en la siguiente línea cuando cabe perfectamente, lo mismo para los resultados. Es como que si se partiera a la mitad.
PD: no, no tengo un montón de `tabs` introducidos en el código

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir "cuando imprimo datos con tabs"? Es tabs un paquete? O es que usas el carácter `\t` en las cadenas? ¿Por qué no pones el código para que se entienda mejor?

Comment: uso el caracter \t

Comment: `\t` no es un "ancho fijo", sino simplemente una orden de "avanzar hasta el siguiente _tabstop_". Si por ejemplo la terminal usa un tabstop de 8, imprimir un `\t` significa básicamente "avanza hasta la siguiente columna cuyo número es múltiplo de 8". Si el último carácter impreso estaba en la columna 3 avanzará 5 espacios, pero si estaba en la columna 7 avanzará sólo 1. Si todo lo que imprimes antes del `\t` ocupa menos de 8 posiciones, eso causará que todo quede alineado verticalmente, pero si alguna fila escribe más de 8 caracteres antes del `\t`, entonces eso  le hará saltar a la columna 16

Comment: Para alinear verticalmente las cosas es mejor, en lugar de tabs, usar formato de cadenas con un tamaño dado para las cadenas. Por ejemplo print("{:20s}".format(txt))` imprimirá `txt` ocupando al menos 20 caracteres (rellenando con espacios si usa menos).

Comment: Aparte de lo antes dicho, el hecho de que tu terminal "parta" la línea, parece obedecer a que tu terminal "piensa" que las líneas que puede mostrar son más cortas. Prueba a escribir `reset` en esa terminal antes de ejecutar tu programa.